# What goes in config.ru for a non-rails app on heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack, resque

I have a simple ruby (non-rails) app that uses resque, and won't start up without config.ru on heroku. When I add a config.ru file I get the following error when running `rackup` locally:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:133:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
from /Users/nickkarrasch/Dropbox/Coding/Ruby/smsnotifyv2/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
```

What do I need to put in config.ru?

Answer (score 6):

The content of that file (**config.ru**), will depend on what you're actually trying to do and the framework you're using since is just used for configuring Rack applications, it tells the `Rack::Builder` what middleware should be used and in which order. These are some of the examples offered in the Heroku documentation [for deploying rack applications.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack):

**Sinatra**:

```
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application
```

**Ramaze**:

```
require ::File.expand_path('./../hello', __FILE__)
Ramaze.start(:file => __FILE__, :started => true)
run Ramaze
```

**Camping**

```
require './hello'
run Rack::Adapter::Camping.new(Hello)
```